# How to Create a arrow PolyLine with curved (geoDesic) using ArcGIS PolyLine

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, line

Trying to draw two markers(points) with a curved and arrow PolyLine using ArcGIS maps.

Below is the source code, able to draw Poly line but it is coming as straight line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
      <title>Simple Map</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/esri/css/esri.css">
      <style>
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }

          #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }

          body {
            background-color: #FFF;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
          }
      </style>

      <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/"></script>

      <script>
      var map;

      require(["esri/map", 
               "esri/geometry/Point", 
               "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
               "esri/graphic",
               "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
               "esri/geometry/Polyline", 
               "dojo/domReady!"], 
              function(Map, Point, 
                        PictureMarkerSymbol, Graphic, 
                        GraphicsLayer, Polyline) {

                var longitude = -12.45;
                var latitude = 37.75;
                var point = new Point(longitude, latitude);
                var layer = new GraphicsLayer();
                map = new Map("map", {
                    basemap: "osm",
                    center: point, // longitude, latitude
                    zoom: 3,
                    maxZoom : 7,
                    minZoom : 3,
                });

                function createMarker(longitude, latitude){
                    var point = new Point(longitude, latitude);
                    point = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(point);
                    var symbol;

                    symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol(
                        "http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/BluePin1LargeB.png", 32, 32)
                        .setOffset(0, 15);
                    var graphic = new Graphic(point, symbol);
                    layer.add(graphic);
                }

                function createPolyLine(sourcePoint, destPoint){
                    var point1 = new Point(sourcePoint[0], sourcePoint[1]);       
                    var point2 = new Point(destPoint[0], destPoint[1]);       
                    var line = new esri.geometry.Polyline();       
                    var lineSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([0,0,255,0.5]),3);  
                    line.addPath([point1, point2]);      

                    var graphic = new Graphic(line, lineSymbol);
                    layer.add(graphic);
                }

                function drawGeoMap(data){
                    console.info(data);
                    for(var row in data){
                        var rowObj = createObject(data[row]);

                        createMarker(rowObj.long, rowObj.lat);
                        createMarker(rowObj.sbLong, rowObj.sbLat);
                        createPolyLine([rowObj.long, rowObj.lat], [rowObj.sbLong, rowObj.sbLat]);
                    }
                    map.addLayer(layer);
                }

                function createObject(rowData){
                    var count = 0;
                    var obj = {
                        sbLat: rowData[count++],
                        sbLong: rowData[count++],
                        sbCountry: rowData[count++],
                        lat: rowData[count++],
                        long: rowData[count++],
                        country: rowData[count++],
                    };
                    return obj;
                }

                drawGeoMap([["22.3511148", "78.6677428", "INDIA", "45.0059", "-93.1059", "UNITED STATES" ]]);

      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any arrow Symbol option and geoDesic (like in Google maps PolyLine) option in ArcGIS PolyLine.

Below is the URL for Google maps PolyLine with arrow and geoDesic option.

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multiplePolylineAnimation.html

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Able to draw curved Polyline(a geodesic line) between two markers. Still looking for arrow at the one end of Polyline.

Thanks to https://gist.github.com/ajturner/4686451. with the help of the code (Esri API example to draw arc) able to draw curved lines.

Changed Polyline creation with geodesicDensify method.

Code change:

```
function createPolyLine(sourcePoint, destPoint){
                    var point1 = new Point(sourcePoint[0], sourcePoint[1]);       
                    var point2 = new Point(destPoint[0], destPoint[1]);   
                    var geographicLine = new Polyline();
                    geographicLine.addPath([point1, point2]);
                    var line = esri.geometry.geodesicDensify(geographicLine, 5000); 

                    var lineSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([0,0,255,0.5]),3);  

                    var graphic = new Graphic(line, lineSymbol);
                    layer.add(graphic);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for arrow in the end of line, you can check this modified [DirectionalLineSymbol](https://github.com/nickcam/DirectionalLineSymbol) js. Thanks to nickcam for his work.

It's makes you can add arrow along the line path OR you can call the end head arrow only. It's also contain animate arrow, so feel free to modified it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes: use geodesicDensify to curve the polyline around the projection.

Then use a CIMSymbol for the line with arrows at equal distances:

```
static LineArrowSymbol = {
        type: "cim", 
        data: {
            type: "CIMSymbolReference",
            symbol: {
                type: "CIMLineSymbol",
                symbolLayers: [{
                    type: "CIMSolidStroke",
                    enable: true,
                    width: 3,
                    color: [255, 0, 0, 255]
                },
                {
                    // arrow symbol
                    type: "CIMVectorMarker",
                    enable: true,
                    size: 5,
                    markerPlacement: {
                        type: "CIMMarkerPlacementAlongLineSameSize", 
                        endings: "NoConstraint",
                        offsetAlongLine: 25,
                        placementTemplate: [50], 
                        angleToLine: true 
                    },
                    frame: {
                        xmin: -5,
                        ymin: -5,
                        xmax: 5,
                        ymax: 5
                    },
                    markerGraphics: [{
                        type: "CIMMarkerGraphic",
                        geometry: {
                            rings: [[[-30, -10], [-30, 10], [0, 0], [-30, -10]]]
                        },
                        symbol: {
                            // fill for the arrow symbol
                            type: "CIMPolygonSymbol",
                            symbolLayers: [{
                                type: "CIMSolidFill",
                                enable: true,
                                color: [255, 0, 0, 255]
                            }]
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }
    };
```

[image]